# Ladda UI not set correct progress

Tags: javascript, metronic

I'm using this code to create a ladda button:

```
CSS:
    <link href="./assets/global/plugins/ladda/ladda-themeless.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

CODE:


<button type="button" id="test" class="btn green mt-ladda-btn ladda-button" data-style="expand-left"> <span class="ladda-label"> <i class="fa fa-key"></i> Nuova Password</span> </button>

JS:

    <script src="./assets/global/plugins/ladda/spin.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="./assets/global/plugins/ladda/ladda.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script>
       Ladda.bind( 'input[type=button]' );
       $(function() {
         $('#test').click(function(e){

            var l = Ladda.create( document.querySelector( '#test' ) );

            // Start loading
            l.start();

            // Will display a progress bar for 50% of the button width
            l.setProgress( 0.5 );
         });
      });
</script>
```

This way the code work but progress is not correct:
[image]

but when use this code js:

```
Ladda.bind( '#test', {
   callback: function( instance ) {
      var progress = 0;
      var interval = setInterval( function() {
         progress = Math.min( progress + Math.random() * 0.1, 1 );
         instance.setProgress( 0.5 );

         if( progress === 1 ) {
            instance.stop();
            clearInterval( interval );
         }
      }, 200 );
   }
});
```

the result is correct: [image]

Why this? I need to use the first code because on click i have some function and i set the progress manualy based on function position.

It is possible to fix? I have metronic license and Material Theme, but u think the problem is plugin not theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand what's going on in the first example you have to look in the Ladda button [code source](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hakimel/Ladda/master/js/ladda.js) and at line 154 there is the `setProgress` function:

```
            /**
             * Sets the width of the visual progress bar inside of
             * this Ladda button
             *
             * @param {Number} progress in the range of 0-1
             */
            setProgress: function( progress ) {

                // Cap it
                progress = Math.max( Math.min( progress, 1 ), 0 );

                var progressElement = button.querySelector( '.ladda-progress' );

                // Remove the progress bar if we're at 0 progress
                if( progress === 0 && progressElement && progressElement.parentNode ) {
                    progressElement.parentNode.removeChild( progressElement );
                }
                else {
                    if( !progressElement ) {
                        progressElement = document.createElement( 'div' );
                        progressElement.className = 'ladda-progress';
                        button.appendChild( progressElement );
                    }

                    progressElement.style.width = ( ( progress || 0 ) * button.offsetWidth ) + 'px';
                }

            }
```

The ladda button in you example has `data-style="expand-left"` setted.
When setProgress in the `else` section it calculate the `.ladda-progress`' width doing:

```
progressElement.style.width = ( ( progress || 0 ) * button.offsetWidth ) + 'px';
```

Now, when it gets `button.offsetWidth` there isn't inside the `expand-left` rules yet.
When expand-left is applied at `.ladda-button` element, it change width dimension because `expand-left` is adding padding-left to it.

```
.ladda-button[data-style="expand-left"][data-loading] {
    padding-left: 56px;
}
```

E.g. `.ladda-button` has an `offsetWidth` of `100px`. 
When you click it the `offsetwidth` will change from `100px` to `156px` because of the `expand-left` css rule above.
But when `setProgress` is called `button.offsetwidth` it will get the `100px` `offsetWidth` because the animation transitions is not happened yet. So when you call `l.setProgress(0.5)` you will see `.ladda-progress` `width` setted to `50px` instead of the correct `78px`.

A quick fix can be this ([jsBin](http://jsbin.com/yevoqizisi/edit?html,output)). Please note that is an ugly hard-coded solution. A better solution it could be the following.
When Ladda instantiate the button it could check the `data-style` attribute and get (for example from an associative array where the keys are only the width-oriented effect name and the value will be the measure) the offeset that will be applied to the `.ladda-button` element.

**EDIT**

> Thanks, but if change progress to 1 the problem not is solved
>   jsbin.com/jonupadono/1/edit?html,output – user3477026

I see. The problem start from this css rule:

```
.ladda-button, .ladda-button .ladda-spinner, .ladda-button .ladda-label {
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275) 0s !important;
}
```

So, when `button.offsetWidth` is called inside `setProgress` it gets a lesser `offsetWidth` because the css animation has not finished yet, it takes 300ms to finish.


**Solution**
Using percentage instead of pixels to calculate the `.ladda-progress`' `width` [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/visufihuna/edit?html,console,output)

Comment: Thanks, but if change progress to 1 the problem not is solved http://jsbin.com/jonupadono/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks!! Perfect now,